# Git Why changes do not reflect on remote repository?

Tags: git

I am trying to setup push to deploy on a vps (a digitalocean droplet), for this I created a repo and initiated it with `--bare`

```
  cd /var
    mkdir demorepo && cd demorepo
    mkdir demo.git && cd demo.git
    git init --bare
```

Now, created a hook named `post-receive` in hooks directory in the repo

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/demo --git-dir =/var/demorepo/demo.git checkout -f
```

set permissions using

```
 chmod +x post-receive
```

On my local machine I created a new repo with `git init` in a folder`\www\demo.git` and added the remote repo as `live`

```
git remote add live ssh://root@extragrip.in/var/demorepo/demo.git
```

**The Problem**
Now I created a new file in the local repo and pushed it using

```
git push live master
```

**The push is successful, But the changes don't reflect on the remote repo.
what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: If you execute the script manually, does it update your working folder in `/var/www/demo`? For instance, was it intentional that you added a space after `--git-dir`?

Comment: I didn't try it . because I don't understand the meaning `#!/bin/sh`. (I wrote it while following a tutorial). (while I try running it manually, can you please help me understand what does it mean  `#!/bin/sh`?)

Comment: Well first you should get your git command working standalone, then you can place it into a post-receive script. If the command can't work standalone, your script won't work either.

Comment: well, I tried it manually and got a message : `fatal: Not a git repository: '=/var/demorepo/demo.git'`. But I initiated it as `git init --bare`. Also, all the git related directories like branches, config, hooks, info, objects, refs, etc. are present in this `demo.git` directory. Even if it is not a git repository, what is the suggested workaround?

Comment: Do you require bare repo?

Comment: Okay... got it. I removed the space before the =/var/demorepo/demo.git and the changes appeared. Thanks. Kindly post an answer

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi, I don't require a bare repo, what do you suggest? Think I will learn something new.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, You are great. you are really a good teacher, that directs the student towards the right answer, instead of spoon feeding. thanks a lot.

Comment: @RameshPareek If you are interested I would suggest about learning bare and non bare git repo http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/

Comment: Ah! Beautiful and simple explanation. Thanks _()_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure hooks work properly you should "debug" them by executing the commands manually.

If/when you get them working manually then you can think about putting them into a hook script.

In this specific question I would expect the command to fail with this error message:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: '=/var/demorepo/demo.git'
```

The reason for this is that you've unintentionally added a space after the `--git-dir` parameter.

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/demo --git-dir =/var/demorepo/demo.git checkout -f
                                       ^
                                       |
                                       +-- here
```

Remove that space and you should be good to go.

You could also remove the equal sign as the following two variants are the same:

```
--git-dir=x
--git-dir x
```

But you can't combine the two as in your case the equal sign is part of the path that git tries to locate, hence the error.